# Woocommerce webhook not sending orders to printify store (Rest API)

Tags: wordpress, rest, woocommerce, webhooks

I am getting this error in the log when can order is created and webhook is initiated to pass the order to printify dashboard -

```
 [Body] => {"error":"ShopNotSetException"}
```

And yes I have set the shop page in woocommerce.

Any ideas on how can I debug this more or solve this. Thank you.

Update - Log for more details -

Update 2  - I was not able to publish from printify to woocommerce but can do so now, by disabling some features in cloudflare, but it did not solve this issue of sending orders from woocommerce to printify.

```
2021-07-25T14:10:16+00:00 INFO Array
(
[Webhook Delivery] => Array
    (
        [Delivery ID] => c05a085b90f7f018fe813aef54ab502e
        [Date] => Jul 25, 2021 @ 14:10
        [URL] => https://api-prod.printify.com/v1/callbacks/woo/orders/created/2744221
        [Duration] => 1.2456
        [Request] => Array
            (
                [Method] => POST
                [Headers] => Array
                    (
                        [User-Agent] => WooCommerce/5.5.1 Hookshot (WordPress/5.8)
                        [Content-Type] => application/json
                        [X-WC-Webhook-Source] => https://storename.com/
                        [X-WC-Webhook-Topic] => action.woocommerce_order_status_processing
                        [X-WC-Webhook-Resource] => action
                        [X-WC-Webhook-Event] => woocommerce_order_status_processing
                        [X-WC-Webhook-Signature] => 1RupIqS5ivp+kigpn34B/71wvPUAQGl+1G/huehhae
                        [X-WC-Webhook-ID] => 1
                        [X-WC-Webhook-Delivery-ID] => c05a085b90f7f018fe813aef54ab50
                    )

            )

        [Body] => {\"action\":\"woocommerce_order_status_processing\",\"arg\":4236}
        [Response] => Array
            (
                [Code] => 200
                [Message] => OK
                [Headers] => Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary Object
                    (
                        [data:protected] => Array
                            (
                                [date] => Sun, 25 Jul 2021 14:10:16 GMT
                                [content-type] => application/json
                                [content-length] => 51
                                [cache-control] => no-cache, private
                                [content-encoding] => gzip
                                [vary] => Accept-Encoding
                                [x-ab-test-token] => d6b46c77-6f12-4c7c-87d5-6fbb444b6e0
                                [x-content-type-options] => nosniff
                                [x-dns-prefetch-control] => off
                                [x-pfy-correlation-id] => aa0dd0c4-363c-401e-857d-12634dad1ed
                                [x-powered-by] => PHP/7.4.20
                                [x-ratelimit-limit] => 3000
                                [x-ratelimit-remaining] => 2999
                                [x-xss-protection] => 1; mode=block
                                [cf-cache-status] => DYNAMIC
                                [expect-ct] => max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
                                [server] => cloudflare
                                [cf-ray] => 6745f87aa92232a-BLR
                            )

                    )

                [Body] => {"error":"ShopNotSetException"}
            )

    )
```

)

Comment: Have you looked here : https://developers.printify.com/#overview ?

Comment: Yes. Couldn't find anything related to "ShopNotSetException" exception

Comment: Add more information, on which API are you hitting, what's the payload?

Comment: @bhanu, To connect woocoomerce store to printify, we just have to add store url on the dashboard, give approval from admin user to publish the products that's it. I have updated the post with log. It has api url. Please check.